# When webrtc connect to STUN, if the public IP's port returned by the STUN is the same as the port that is webrtc create socket with STUN used?

Tags: webrtc, stun

I find when the webrtc create socket with STUN , the port return by STUN always same as the socket port. Is it accidental or fixed?

Answer (score 1):

This depends on the type of NAT you're behind, some NATs may translate the port as well.

Comment: I use symmetric nat,it will use the same port?

Comment: @Y.Thomas - it will use the same *local* port, but the remote endpoint will see a different port value since the NAT translated it to something else for that remote ip.

Answer (score 0):

It's called port preservation in NAT terminology. Port numbers are preserved unless there is a conflict which happens when you have more than one machine behind NAT accessing the same service.

Comment: After the port mapping is successfully established, must the internet send data be sent through the mapping port? Or just create the port mapping , After the p2p connection is established, the intranet sends data do not use the mapped port ?